# How to edit and replace a specific line of code in a textfile which contains commas to separate them?

Tags: vb.net

I'm creating a program which acts like a shop. The shopkeeper creates a new product and it writes the name,price,GTIN-8 code and the quantity of the product available. When the customer purchases an item using the GTIN-8 code and specifies the quantity, the program should update the textfile and change the amount of stock left. E.G. if there are 50 tables and the user purchases 10, the textfile should update and and show 40 afterwards.

**MY CODE**

```
    Dim aLine As String = ""
    Dim theField As String = ""
    Dim aChar As Char

    findstring = IO.File.OpenText("Stock.txt")

    Do Until findstring.EndOfStream

        aLine = findstring.ReadLine()

        theField = ""
        GtinField = ""
        NameField = ""
        PriceField = ""

        For i = 0 To aLine.Length() - 1
            aChar = aLine(i)
            If aChar <> "," Then
                theField = theField + aChar
            Else
                If GtinField = "" Then
                    GtinField = theField
                ElseIf NameField = "" Then
                    NameField = theField

                End If
                theField = ""
            End If
        Next
        PriceField = theField

        If GtinField = txtGTIN.Text Then

            receipt.lstreceipt.Items.Add(GtinField & Space(3) & NameField & Space(2) & txtquantity.Text & Space(2) & PriceField & Space(2) & "£" & PriceField * txtquantity.Text)
            finalPrice = finalPrice + (PriceField * txtQuantity.Text)
        End If

        theField = ""

    Loop

    findstring.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: Could you explain why you don't use a database for this task?

Comment: I'm fairly new to vb so my knowledge of databases is limited.

Comment: Sounds like a Learning Opportunity!  The problem with a text file is that they are not random access.  You will have to rewrite the entire thing each time.

Comment: I suggest you to define a class that represents your product. Then create a List of this class, read everything from your file creating an instance of your class for every line, Add it to your list. Whenever you sell something update the instance of the product and rewrite the list to your file. A lot of work, perhaps you could try to learn something about a database and how it works

Comment: As Plutonix suggested, you should use a database (or perhaps an Excel spreadsheet) instead of a text file.  You don't want to have to rewrite the entire text file every time something changes.

Comment: This task is part of one of my homework assignments and i am required to use a textfile.

Comment: Is the assignemtn about how to parse a string? If not consider using https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx

Comment: If using a text file rather than a database is a requirement of the assignment then why did you give your reason for not using a database as the fact that you're not familiar with them?  If you're not going to give us accurate information when we ask for it then you're less likely to get the help you want.